# Unit test for a lambda expression

Tags: java, unit-testing, lambda

I am trying to a function:
I have a function like this:

```
public static void myFunction() {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
        list.forEach(num -> {
            checkNumber(num);
        });
    }
   
public static void checkNumber(Integer num) throws RuntimeException {

        try {
            if(num.equals(3))
                throw new RuntimeException("3 found not to execute");
            System.out.println("mynum:"+num);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

The `try-catch` block in the `checkNumber` method is added to handle the exception gracefully so that the `myFunction` executes properly for the whole list.
My target is to write unit test for `myFunction` method to see if the list is executed successfully for cases when the exception is thrown.

I can easily write test case for the second method and catch the exception but not sure how to ensure that lambda expression from the first method has executed the complete list even if an exception is thrown in the second method.
Any suggestion please?

Comment: @Sweeper, no, I want to confirm if my lambda expression has iterated over the list completely or not.

Comment: actually, this is just a demo code, in reality, something goes there instead of console printing. I just want to make sure if the list has been iterated after introducing the try-catch block in the second method or not.  Executing the list is the target, not other outputs

Comment: Okay, then just observe effects of whatever that "something" that "goes there" is?

Answer (score 0):

You refactor for better testability:

```
public static void myFunction() {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
        checkList(list);
    }


// test this, that way you can input lists you know to trigger the exception
public static void checkList(List<Integer> list) {
          list.forEach(num -> {
            checkNumber(num);
        });
}
   
public static void checkNumber(Integer num) throws RuntimeException {

        try {
            if(num.equals(3))
                throw new RuntimeException("3 found not to execute");
            System.out.println("mynum:"+num);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the test case, how do I test that checkList method iterated through the whole list?

Comment: @user404 `List.forEach` is not lazy. Iteration has completed when `checkList` returns.

Comment: @Jorn, sorry I am not following about ```List.forEach is not lazy``` part. Can you please give an example?